# Google Static Maps API with encoded polyline

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-maps-static-api, google-directory-api

I have made a request to google directions API and recived the following JSON directions:

(file to large to copy here)
    https://gist.githubusercontent.com/crooksey/9930819/raw/947e4d17a93ca94b78216d92fbd94b281966dede/directions_api

At the bottom, I get the encoded polyline data:

```
ecduHxqrE|RfS{SlW_w@zDc{@ig@cVlK}z@j}Aog@z{AuGbdDibAfkGaBpcG}~@vrGy_AhhCoi@feB{bBxu@kxAsSus@|eAcLdyBci@dcByi@ly@`GrgC_S~d@e\\wBugA_uBwuAusAoaCidAs~Dq{DiaAu`CuwAweAevBi@}dDwgCsrAwfBuqFkmBwzEu~DenAa|Bi_BcuDmrAghF_{B_hGa{@chAocAl[m_@pXwk@{z@}Zc~A_hAmn@mdAinBg_@eD{o@moA{_@kz@sn@ca@oWmcCoQsUue@`De{@yH{oA~i@meAliA}wAa]ij@qg@}o@w_@yVrT_k@|Y{oCi`@e_@RqEjOvUx\\`TjDv@yi@ttA~Gr}@`Fxi@ad@v]yJ|gAxlAjsAz_@|l@oYzbBatAn_CdJdSv_B~f@rlAhk@`j@f_@`rAhpAfs@f`@`kAfg@`Nr_AbgBtNt~@nb@vRlc@gXry@}Wd^iIdv@zfCvgCj{GlcAzxEnkDfkGlgGtpE|eEf{AvzBx{BzvA|_B~\\yAjyBxJzwA|wA~_AznBlgAt_AbhBpsB`xChzAxsA|uAxVnxBnPb}AzCx`EnhA`qDwCnpG~SvrCbmA|lCd{B~jFdZzbCn{@b`EhqA|aBb_Ad}BdkBxjEx[vgC|HluEfUnkBtfB`eF~mAzjD`V~q@y_@pnEtv@byChn@tv@`dBjoFz_@KdbElc@f]|My@bc@da@mKptA`Nhj@aq@fHlAbK~M?Z_UyOw^ji@su@Ju|@`qEX`cBnw@|lAsRjlD_q@~nHgA`vH}m@hvEs]gL~AzkCt[hiCcJlvFuAzzE`a@jbDnlBxyG||C|~B`d@juCaiAf`DoQf`HhS|jBLpmBuLd`Dma@zsBc[ftGcx@t|H{TnyGxTzdA_Bn[kPysBhZm`HvvAk`Rdb@ehBoBypCdF}hB_YgcAzMqx@nEohGriAi~Ca_@mpCopCkoBwpC_iIaKegKlIu{EuX_{CgD{pBs^oXuu@kpEqZmzDymBmwDt`@qkEhEmzCjCiyBqSonCmKm|@rRweC{R}cBw{@{fDeo@}u@q|@g}Cx_@quEqdBcyEs}Ba_HoQ{dJysDyvIiiBejDup@e{D{mAuxDes@a_BcoBkdGgEweJp|AkTl{@u_@lg@_{Afp@suDzBmgAmLyp@qw@sx@wdAafA_~BukA`bAmeBfl@orEtn@}f@xkAbVptAgk@xv@{}A|p@cyAhjAsiHpEkyFbaAceHvLe~Dli@a~Ary@eeBx}@lUbb@jVzf@_NhKs^yH{I
```

Now In theory I should be able to display this route on a map, as easy as..

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x400&path=weight:10%7Ccolor:orange%7Cenc:ecduHxqrE|RfS{SlW_w@zDc{@ig@cVlK}z@j}Aog@z{AuGbdDibAfkGaBpcG}~@vrGy_AhhCoi@feB{bBxu@kxAsSus@|eAcLdyBci@dcByi@ly@`GrgC_S~d@e\\wBugA_uBwuAusAoaCidAs~Dq{DiaAu`CuwAweAevBi@}dDwgCsrAwfBuqFkmBwzEu~DenAa|Bi_BcuDmrAghF_{B_hGa{@chAocAl[m_@pXwk@{z@}Zc~A_hAmn@mdAinBg_@eD{o@moA{_@kz@sn@ca@oWmcCoQsUue@`De{@yH{oA~i@meAliA}wAa]ij@qg@}o@w_@yVrT_k@|Y{oCi`@e_@RqEjOvUx\\`TjDv@yi@ttA~Gr}@`Fxi@ad@v]yJ|gAxlAjsAz_@|l@oYzbBatAn_CdJdSv_B~f@rlAhk@`j@f_@`rAhpAfs@f`@`kAfg@`Nr_AbgBtNt~@nb@vRlc@gXry@}Wd^iIdv@zfCvgCj{GlcAzxEnkDfkGlgGtpE|eEf{AvzBx{BzvA|_B~\\yAjyBxJzwA|wA~_AznBlgAt_AbhBpsB`xChzAxsA|uAxVnxBnPb}AzCx`EnhA`qDwCnpG~SvrCbmA|lCd{B~jFdZzbCn{@b`EhqA|aBb_Ad}BdkBxjEx[vgC|HluEfUnkBtfB`eF~mAzjD`V~q@y_@pnEtv@byChn@tv@`dBjoFz_@KdbElc@f]|My@bc@da@mKptA`Nhj@aq@fHlAbK~M?Z_UyOw^ji@su@Ju|@`qEX`cBnw@|lAsRjlD_q@~nHgA`vH}m@hvEs]gL~AzkCt[hiCcJlvFuAzzE`a@jbDnlBxyG||C|~B`d@juCaiAf`DoQf`HhS|jBLpmBuLd`Dma@zsBc[ftGcx@t|H{TnyGxTzdA_Bn[kPysBhZm`HvvAk`Rdb@ehBoBypCdF}hB_YgcAzMqx@nEohGriAi~Ca_@mpCopCkoBwpC_iIaKegKlIu{EuX_{CgD{pBs^oXuu@kpEqZmzDymBmwDt`@qkEhEmzCjCiyBqSonCmKm|@rRweC{R}cBw{@{fDeo@}u@q|@g}Cx_@quEqdBcyEs}Ba_HoQ{dJysDyvIiiBejDup@e{D{mAuxDes@a_BcoBkdGgEweJp|AkTl{@u_@lg@_{Afp@suDzBmgAmLyp@qw@sx@wdAafA_~BukA`bAmeBfl@orEtn@}f@xkAbVptAgk@xv@{}A|p@cyAhjAsiHpEkyFbaAceHvLe~Dli@a~Ary@eeBx}@lUbb@jVzf@_NhKs^yH{I&sensor=true
```

But alas, this does not work, anyone have any ideas as to why? It should be a fairly basic exercise. As it's just using googles own API.

Comment: Well that's a good question and I can't figure out why this doesn't work :(

Comment: I'm not sure if URL size limit is reached. Using just the first 8 points I got map of Portsmouth harbour with polyline. In that case URL was very short comparing to original one.

Comment: No its not the size limit, as I can increase it with random locations and it reaches the size length. But not as it is.

Comment: Right. This URL is around 1300 characters. I think under 2000, you should be good to go. And yes, removing a few points at the end gives you the map and polyline.

Comment: How can I trim this consistently in a production environment then? Can you post the working URL?

Comment: Well the thing is that you should not need to trim it... That one works: http://goo.gl/6YJ1pY

Comment: possible duplicate of [Directions API overview\_polyline doesn't have correct points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13360928/directions-api-overview-polyline-doesnt-have-correct-points)

Comment: Removing one '\' from '...\\wBugA' it seems produce whole polyline. Otherwise it breaks with 96 coordinate points.

Comment: @AntoJurković That's right. It works, but it doesn't seem to be the same route at all if you compare to my trimmed URL. Strange. I double checked the doc and it clearly states that URLs should be under 2048 characters, which is the case here. And removing all double backslashes gives me yet another route.

Comment: Do you get the expected route using https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility ?

Comment: No, the route is completely wrong.

Comment: Removing the "/" like you said works: http://goo.gl/pKzlGB

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems the polyline overview used a lot of "\\" which causes the problem, so I replaced all instance of "\\" with "\".

Used python replace on the string to sort it.

```
string_new = string.replace("\\\\", "\\")
```