# Google Static Maps show polyline using Encoded Route

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to get the Google Map Static Image which show both origin,destination along with poly line using the Encoded Route data which I have but I was not able see anything on the map.

below is the link which I am using

```
`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=600x400&path=enc:i}cyHdpc@@?L?@bBAZERwHhNw@zBONULXbC}FjAwBh@eGbB[LGJW]gAmB_@w@_@w@_HnLgDrFqAhBSTQDMn@QfAcApF?^B\\Rl@z@xAL`@IR]RqA\\YF]@c@NcALWPWZeBbBuFdE}D~CuBlAgA~@c@\\OCy@b@eBb@_DpAuDjBw@n@]v@c@tBe@fBWj@k@d@mExByB|@qBpAYFgABc@N}@f@s@l@e@b@_AvA{E|JoAvB_ApAKLaCaH[kBW{CEa@GcBQ}AUuAg@}BsCcKiDgN_AwDmBxAkB`BWm@KoAWQMB&key={API_KEY}`
```

Things to note :

1. My URL is below 2000 characters
2. I am using `path` parameter as per documentation using `enc:` tag
3. I have tried replacing `\\` with `\\\\` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22839246/google-static-maps-api-with-encoded-polyline)

but none of them worked out.is there anything here which I am missing ?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Google Maps Polyline Decoder]

If you carefully check [Google Maps Polyline Utility](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility) it is appending `@` at the end of the encoded polyline entered.

by appending `@` at the end of the Encoded polyline path I was able to get the Google Static Image with path drawn on it.

Valid Link:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=600x400&path=enc%3Ai}cyHdpc@@?L?@bBAZERwHhNw@zBONULXbC}FjAwBh@eGbB[LGJW]gAmB_@w@_@w@_HnLgDrFqAhBSTQDMn@QfAcApF?^B\\\\Rl@z@xAL`@IR]RqA\\\\YF]@c@NcALWPWZeBbBuFdE}D~CuBlAgA~@c@\\\\OCy@b@eBb@_DpAuDjBw@n@]v@c@tBe@fBWj@k@d@mExByB|@qBpAYFgABc@N}@f@s@l@e@b@_AvA{E|JoAvB_ApAKLaCaH[kBW{CEa@GcBQ}AUuAg@}BsCcKiDgN_AwDmBxAkB`BWm@KoAWQMB@
```

Comment: I think the `@` symbol is very hit and miss, sometimes you need it, sometimes you don't, which is very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this is that the browser does not recognize the ('\\') double backslash. I recommend to replace it by its encoded representation for URLs, i.e. replace every double back slash ('\\') by '%5C'.

**DOES NOT CHANGE THE POLYLINE AS THE 'CORRECT' ANSWER SAYS.**

In python:

```
# this is the same url in the question
your_url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=600x400&path=enc:i}cyHdpc@@?L?@bBAZERwHhNw@zBONULXbC}FjAwBh@eGbB[LGJW]gAmB_@w@_@w@_HnLgDrFqAhBSTQDMn@QfAcApF?^B\\Rl@z@xAL`@IR]RqA\\YF]@c@NcALWPWZeBbBuFdE}D~CuBlAgA~@c@\\OCy@b@eBb@_DpAuDjBw@n@]v@c@tBe@fBWj@k@d@mExByB|@qBpAYFgABc@N}@f@s@l@e@b@_AvA{E|JoAvB_ApAKLaCaH[kBW{CEa@GcBQ}AUuAg@}BsCcKiDgN_AwDmBxAkB`BWm@KoAWQMB&key={API_KEY}"

valid_url = your_url.replace("\\", "%5C")
```

The resulting image for this is:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mq5Bk.png

---

This is the resulting image provided in the "correct" answer:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7c4Tj.png