# improve draw encoded polyline google maps API V3 Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

so I've been using google maps v3 library for my current project right now. all works fine except custom polylines that I've been working on right now

I've learnt that you could decode the encoded polylines using for example :

```
var encoded_data = "ud|{H_igZ??F~BLpEGhCJdAXt@CUERF^\nBl@|BWvA^\JbAd@tCNbBhAhGLpABfCZdBCjAu@nA\`AJBLJF?DAp@r@E\C?Ab@@l@FLVDJIHBFWLLHHQVM@GARb@EIbB`@cAm@Mr@";

var decode = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(encoded_data);
```

and draw the polyline using :

```
var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
                                path: decode,
                                strokeColor: '#00008B',
                                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                                strokeWeight: 4,
                                zIndex: 3
                            });

line.setMap(map);
lineArray.push(line);
```

all works fine, but I've been wondering since sometimes the drawn polylines is not really good and what I mean by good sometimes the polylines didn't following the roads..

so my question is, is there a way that we could draw the decoded polyline in a better shape ? like following the exact road like we wanted to ? I heard this google map library called **[Direction service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions)** but is it related to my problem ?

Comment: a polyline is as it is, when the encoded polyline doesn't "look good" it will not look better when it's decoded

Comment: are your use **overview_polyline**?? of **directionsService.route**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Directions API overview_polyline doesn't have correct points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13360928/directions-api-overview-polyline-doesnt-have-correct-points/13361860#13361860)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get a polyline from Google maps directions V3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180104/get-a-polyline-from-google-maps-directions-v3)

Comment: Do you have an example of what the posted encoded polyline _should_ look like? [this is what I see](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/3ah5v43b/), is it correct?  Where did it come from? Do the "\" characters need to be escaped?

Comment: @Dr.Molle yap that is why I've made this question because I want to know if there are a way to make the decoded routes more precission on the road

Comment: @HoangHieu actually not yet, I want to ask is there a way to achieve it

Comment: @geocodezip I wish that when I use another library the routes will look like this... http://i.stack.imgur.com/JdGcr.png. the one that I gave you actually was the return response from my backend server.. so the idea was using my decoded polylines and another library (if exist) the routes would be more better displayed

Comment: Have a function decode Polylines in java :3, you can convert it to any language... 
http://jeffreysambells.com/2010/05/27/decoding-polylines-from-google-maps-direction-api-with-java

Comment: the problem is the decode processing is done on the frontend side using javascript :( @HoangHieu