# Sending googlemap Polygon in Querystring

Tags: google-maps

We need to send a googlemap polygon as a querystring parameter. We have noticed on sites such as Rightmove.co.uk and other sites, the polygon parameter is encoded. For example, a 3 sided polygon is encoded as polygon=qntyHnjq%40jhAyv%40k%5CduC. Is this a special standard for sending polygons as querystring paramters. How does one encode the polygon to this format.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use the encoding algorithm used by the Google Maps JavaScript API v3.

My answer to the question: [Directions API overview_polyline doesn't have correct points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13360928/directions-api-overview-polyline-doesnt-have-correct-points) contains some links to information on that algorithm:

https://web.archive.org/web/20131122011459/http://facstaff.unca.edu/mcmcclur/GoogleMaps/EncodePolyline/

A quick test with the encoded string you provided yields a triangle in Brent Park, UK (north west of London).

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var polygonStr = "qntyHnjq%40jhAyv%40k%5CduC";
  var unencodedPolypath = decodeURIComponent(polygonStr);
  console.log(unencodedPolypath);
  var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
    map: map,
    path: google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(unencodedPolypath)
  });
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < polygon.getPaths().getAt(0).getLength(); i++) {
    bounds.extend(polygon.getPaths().getAt(0).getAt(i));
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: This snippet no longer works due to API changes by google

Comment: Updated snippet to add a google test key so it functions.